# How to get SUB from aws cognito token

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use the cognito generated unique id knows as SUB to be a PK in my tables. But I am not able to get this SUB in the response of the first sign-up call. I am using the latest version of the sdk for android:

```
aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.9.1
```

Can somebody guide me on how or where I can get this id?

The same question was asked on this thread but none of them works https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/335

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sub from the ID token (which is a JWT) after you have signed in. After you have signed in using the AWSMobileClient, you can do something like the following to get the sub

```
 AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getClaim("sub")
```

Comment: Thanks Bommas, but I wanted the SUB before the first sign in. After the first successful sign-up call to cognito and before initiating the  account activation process, that is when I wanted to get the SUB. Of course after signing in it will be in the JWT token.

Comment: @Natsen, I work on the AWS Mobile SDK team will take this as a feature request to the team. If you don't mind, can you create a new github issue here ( https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues) for tracking.

Comment: Bommas as I have mentioned in the question this was raised before. Please check this link https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/335. But wasn't resolved.

Comment: @Natsen, To better track this issue specifically for android please open an issue here https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues

Comment: @Natsen This is being tracked in https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/635 issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

sub can be taken if we have accesstoken

CognitoJWTParser.getClaim(accessToken.getJWTToken(), "sub")